# not able to store cookie value in cookies

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I am not able to store a cookie value in a cookie. Here is my code:

```
namespace CookieCreation.Controllers
{
    public class CookieController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        { 
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult WriteCookie(String CookieName, String CookieValue, bool IsPersistent)
        {
            if (IsPersistent)
            { 
                CookieOptions cookies = new CookieOptions();
                cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName, CookieValue, cookies);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName, CookieValue);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = ("Sucessful");
            return View("Index");
        }       

        public IActionResult ReadCookie()
        {
            ViewBag.CookieValue = Request.Cookies["CookieName"];
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you determine that the cookie is not stored? Use Chrome developer tools, Application/Cookies to see if the cookie is created.

I used your code with the Index.cshtml below and everything worked, cookie is stored and read using your code:

```
<h1>Index</h1>
<p>Last operation: @ViewBag.Message</p>

@{
    using(Html.BeginForm("WriteCookie", "Cookie", new { CookieName = "CookieName", IsPersistent = false}, FormMethod.Post  )) {
        <input type="text" value="42" name="CookieValue" />
        <input type="submit" value="post"/>
    }
}
```